# PHP - SOAP xml returning empty when SimpleXmlElement object created

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I've been trying to figure this out for over an hour now, and I give up. I'm getting the following response from a webservice.

I want to be able to get access to the children of Fault (I have this working for another webservice call, but for some reason, which I believe MIGHT be namespace related, this one doesn't work).

```
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Invalid Scope</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <faultresponse xmlns="xsd url" xmlns:ns2="xsd url">
                    <transactionid>TEST</transactionid>
                    <errorcode>ERR-4223</errorcode>
                </faultresponse>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:envelope>
```

My PHP code is pretty simple. Firstly, I create the SimpleXmlElement object from the above xml.

I get a list of namespaces in the xml (which it picks up two: "soap", and ""). I then get the children of the XML in the soap: namespace.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response_xml);
$namespace = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$soap = $xml->children($namespace['soap']);
```

Given the above code. I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
$fault_fields = $soap->Body->children()->Fault->children();

foreach ($fault_fields as $field):
   echo (string) $field->getName() . ' - ' . $field[0] . '<br />';
endforeach;
```

However, if I run $soap->asXML(); I can see the following:

```
<soap:Body>
            <soap:Fault>
                <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
                <faultstring>Invalid Scope</faultstring>
                <detail>
                    <faultresponse xmlns="xsd url" xmlns:ns2="xsd url">
                        <transactionid>TEST</transactionid>
                        <errorcode>ERR-4223</errorcode>
                    </faultresponse>
                </detail>
            </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
```

But if I try to go to access Body or Fault:

```
$soap = &$this->parse_soap_body($response_xml);
$body = $soap->Body->children()->Fault->children();
echo $body->asXML();
```

I get a Node no longer exists error with the stack returning this XML.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Invalid Scope</faultstring>
.... more xml
```

This is seriously doing my head in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.